# After applying Android Studio 2.3.3 suggested changes (to remove warnings) I now get either of two errors. What to do?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, database-connection, intentservice

Here's a little background. The process of querying the database (`QueryDB`) in my app begins in `MainActivity.onCreate`, where I have this code:

```
assets = getAssets(); // the SQLite database

DatabaseConnector 
  dbc = new DatabaseConnector(getApplicationContext(), assets);
  dbc.setDbProcesslistener(this); // set way to know matches has been defined
  dbc.findDBMatches();
```

And in the file in my question (named `DatabaseConnector`) I have:

```
  void findDBMatches()
  {
    mContext.startService(new Intent(mContext, QueryDB.class));
  }
```

Here's where the problem manifests itself. This code segment ...

```
  public static class QueryDB extends IntentService
  {
    public QueryDB(String name)
    {
      super(name);
    }
```

results in this error:

`? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
    ? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
    com.dslomer64.servyhelperton E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dslomer64.servyhelperton, PID: 335
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service 
        com.dslomer64.servyhelperton.DatabaseConnector$QueryDB: 
    java.lang.InstantiationException: class`
      `com.dslomer64.servyhelperton.DatabaseConnector$QueryDB` **has no zero argument constructor**

The error doesn't tell me a line, but it does mention `QueryDB`. So I insert a zero-argument constructor for `QueryDB` and get an immediate error:

[image]

I circled `extends IntentService` because, in `findDBMatches`, I start a service for `QueryDB` and the first error message says `Unable to instantiate service`. However, in debugging, I found that execution didn't fail at the line `mContext.startService(new Intent(mContext, QueryDB.class));`. I had breakpoints set in the constructors for `QueryDB` but execution didn't go there.

**I'm lost.**

Before (foolishly) taking AS's advice about changes, the app worked fine. Now I could go back through the history and revert to the version before I began the changes, but there were plenty (of warnings) that I got rid of and I'd rather not do that. **If anyone can, with such short snippets of code, suggest a fix, I can try it and maybe be good to go.**

Further notes:

App won't work without `QueryDB` extending `IntentService` (get other immediate errors).

Note that `mContext` WAS declared `static` (which I now know not to do because of memory leaks) but it doesn't matter whether it's `static` or not. Same errors.

Answer (score 0):

use `super("QueryDB");` inside the constructor

```
public QueryDB {
super("QueryDB");
}
```

Comment: Well, that gets rid of both errors, but there's another error causing phone to crash and the Logcat has many lines saying `com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.` So I can't say it's fixed, but I'm past where I was. What the heck is going on? I've been getting that message hundreds of times, off and on, all day. Restarting or clearing Logcat accomplishes nothing. Will exit AS and use different emulator and eventually my phone to see if I finally get location of error.

Comment: Not that did NOT get rid of both errors. Well it DID, but now there's a sort of predictable NEW error: `                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.dslomer64.servyhelperton.DatabaseConnector$QueryDB: java.lang.IllegalAccessException:` **access to constructor not allowed**. I really doubted that your suggestion would solve my problem. Moreover, **it isn't even legal**.

Comment: post your code to check it.do you mean that my solution did not help?

Comment: i think that something wrong with your database connection. or incorrect data inside the db

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/5707b21/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/RichInputConnection.java

Comment: sorry your suggestion gave the error "DatabaseConnector$QueryDB: java.lang.IllegalAccessException:` access to constructor not allowed," meaning you can't do `public QueryDB {
super("QueryDB"); // accessing the constructor
}`

Comment: I can't post code of 800 lines (this class) and there are many classes. I wouldn't want to spend time making a SSCE whatever it's called. It might lead me to the error, though. It's like I said: there's minimal code and I don't expect anyone to spend much time on it. The amount of time you probably spent is about the max I'd want anybody to spend. Thanks for trying to help. I'll look at the link. This huge app has worked flawlessly until I tried to incorporate a few options that were more complex than I thought. I'll get out of it, if only by going back two days to when there were no problems.